# jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are many questions related to this problem. I have read them all but I am not still able to fix my problem. I am getting this error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
>       at initCustomDropdown (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/****/lib/js/custom.js:116:15)
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/****/lib/js/custom.js:45:2)
>       at l (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/jessica/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29375)
>       at c (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/****/lib/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677) undefined

However I am not able to get the point. My `custom.js` line number 116 is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  /* 
  1. Vars and Inits
  */

  var menuActive = false;
  var header = $('.header');

  setHeader();

  initCustomDropdown();
  initPageMenu();
  initDealsSlider();
  initTabLines();
  initFeaturedSlider();
  featuredSliderZIndex();
  initPopularSlider();
  initBanner2Slider();
  initFavs();
  initArrivalsSlider();
  arrivalsSliderZIndex();
  bestsellersSlider();
  initTabs();
  initTrendsSlider();
  initReviewsSlider();
  initViewedSlider();
  initBrandsSlider();
  initTimer();

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    setHeader();
    featuredSliderZIndex();
    initTabLines();
  });

  /* 
  2. Set Header
  */

  function setHeader() {
    //To pin main nav to the top of the page when it's reached
    //uncomment the following

    // var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller(
    // {
    //  globalSceneOptions:
    //  {
    //      triggerHook: 'onLeave'
    //  }
    // });

    // var pin = new ScrollMagic.Scene(
    // {
    //  triggerElement: '.main_nav'
    // })
    // .setPin('.main_nav').addTo(controller);

    if (window.innerWidth > 991 && menuActive) {
      closeMenu();
    }
  }

  /* 
  3. Init Custom Dropdown
  */

  function initCustomDropdown() {
    var placeholder;
    if ($('.custom_dropdown_placeholder').length && $('.custom_list').length) {
      placeholder = $('.custom_dropdown_placeholder');
      var list = $('.custom_list');
    }
    if (placeholder) {

      placeholder.on('click', function(ev) {
        if (list.hasClass('active')) {
          list.removeClass('active');
        } else {
          list.addClass('active');
        }

        $(document).one('click', function closeForm(e) {
          if ($(e.target).hasClass('clc')) {
            $(document).one('click', closeForm);
          } else {
            list.removeClass('active');
          }
        });

      });
    }

    $('.custom_list a').on('click', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      var index = $(this).parent().index();

      placeholder.text($(this).text()).css('opacity', '1');

      if (list.hasClass('active')) {
        list.removeClass('active');
      } else {
        list.addClass('active');
      }
    });


    $('select').on('change', function(e) {
      placeholder.text(this.value);

      $(this).animate({
        width: placeholder.width() + 'px'
      });
    });
  }

  /* 
  4. Init Page Menu
  */

  function initPageMenu() {
    if ($('.page_menu').length && $('.page_menu_content').length) {
      var menu = $('.page_menu');
      var menuContent = $('.page_menu_content');
      var menuTrigger = $('.menu_trigger');

      //Open / close page menu
      menuTrigger.on('click', function() {
        if (!menuActive) {
          openMenu();
        } else {
          closeMenu();
        }
      });

      //Handle page menu
      if ($('.page_menu_item').length) {
        var items = $('.page_menu_item');
        items.each(function() {
          var item = $(this);
          if (item.hasClass("has-children")) {
            item.on('click', function(evt) {
              evt.preventDefault();
              evt.stopPropagation();
              var subItem = item.find('> ul');
              if (subItem.hasClass('active')) {
                subItem.toggleClass('active');
                TweenMax.to(subItem, 0.3, {
                  height: 0
                });
              } else {
                subItem.toggleClass('active');
                TweenMax.set(subItem, {
                  height: "auto"
                });
                TweenMax.from(subItem, 0.3, {
                  height: 0
                });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  function openMenu() {
    var menu = $('.page_menu');
    var menuContent = $('.page_menu_content');
    TweenMax.set(menuContent, {
      height: "auto"
    });
    TweenMax.from(menuContent, 0.3, {
      height: 0
    });
    menuActive = true;
  }

  function closeMenu() {
    var menu = $('.page_menu');
    var menuContent = $('.page_menu_content');
    TweenMax.to(menuContent, 0.3, {
      height: 0
    });
    menuActive = false;
  }

  /* 
  5. Init Deals Slider
  */

  function initDealsSlider() {
    if ($('.deals_slider').length) {
      var dealsSlider = $('.deals_slider');
      dealsSlider.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: false,
        navClass: ['deals_slider_prev', 'deals_slider_next'],
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        smartSpeed: 1200,
        margin: 30,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000
      });

      if ($('.deals_slider_prev').length) {
        var prev = $('.deals_slider_prev');
        prev.on('click', function() {
          dealsSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
        });
      }

      if ($('.deals_slider_next').length) {
        var next = $('.deals_slider_next');
        next.on('click', function() {
          dealsSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
        });
      }
    }
  }

  /* 
  6. Init Tab Lines
  */

  function initTabLines() {
    if ($('.tabs').length) {
      var tabs = $('.tabs');

      tabs.each(function() {
        var tabsItem = $(this);
        var tabsLine = tabsItem.find('.tabs_line span');
        var tabGroup = tabsItem.find('ul li');

        var posX = $(tabGroup[0]).position().left;
        tabsLine.css({
          'left': posX,
          'width': $(tabGroup[0]).width()
        });
        tabGroup.each(function() {
          var tab = $(this);
          tab.on('click', function() {
            if (!tab.hasClass('active')) {
              tabGroup.removeClass('active');
              tab.toggleClass('active');
              var tabXPos = tab.position().left;
              var tabWidth = tab.width();
              tabsLine.css({
                'left': tabXPos,
                'width': tabWidth
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }

  /* 
  7. Init Tabs
  */

  function initTabs() {
    if ($('.tabbed_container').length) {
      //Handle tabs switching
      var tabsContainers = $('.tabbed_container');
      tabsContainers.each(function() {
        var tabContainer = $(this);
        var tabs = tabContainer.find('.tabs ul li');
        var panels = tabContainer.find('.panel');
        var sliders = panels.find('.slider');

        tabs.each(function() {
          var tab = $(this);
          tab.on('click', function() {
            panels.removeClass('active');
            var tabIndex = tabs.index(this);
            $($(panels[tabIndex]).addClass('active'));
            sliders.slick("unslick");
            sliders.each(function() {
              var slider = $(this);
              // slider.slick("unslick");
              if (slider.hasClass('bestsellers_slider')) {
                initBSSlider(slider);
              }
              if (slider.hasClass('featured_slider')) {
                initFSlider(slider);
              }
              if (slider.hasClass('arrivals_slider')) {
                initASlider(slider);
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }

  /* 
  8. Init Featured Slider
  */

  function initFeaturedSlider() {
    if ($('.featured_slider').length) {
      var featuredSliders = $('.featured_slider');
      featuredSliders.each(function() {
        var featuredSlider = $(this);
        initFSlider(featuredSlider);
      });

    }
  }

  function initFSlider(fs) {
    var featuredSlider = fs;
    featuredSlider.on('init', function() {
        var activeItems = featuredSlider.find('.slick-slide.slick-active');
        for (var x = 0; x < activeItems.length - 1; x++) {
          var item = $(activeItems[x]);
          item.find('.border_active').removeClass('active');
          if (item.hasClass('slick-active')) {
            item.find('.border_active').addClass('active');
          }
        }
      }).on({
        afterChange: function(event, slick, current_slide_index, next_slide_index) {
          var activeItems = featuredSlider.find('.slick-slide.slick-active');
          activeItems.find('.border_active').removeClass('active');
          for (var x = 0; x < activeItems.length - 1; x++) {
            var item = $(activeItems[x]);
            item.find('.border_active').removeClass('active');
            if (item.hasClass('slick-active')) {
              item.find('.border_active').addClass('active');
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .slick({
        rows: 2,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        infinite: false,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              rows: 2,
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3,
              dots: true
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 575,
            settings: {
              rows: 2,
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2,
              dots: false
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              rows: 1,
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              dots: false
            }
          }
        ]
      });
  }

  /* 
  9. Init Favorites
  */

  function initFavs() {
    // Handle Favorites
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('product_fav');
    for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
      var item = items[x];
      item.addEventListener('click', function(fn) {
        fn.target.classList.toggle('active');
      });
    }
  }

  /* 
  10. Init ZIndex
  */

  function featuredSliderZIndex() {
    // Hide slider dots on item hover
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('featured_slider_item');

    for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
      var item = items[x];
      item.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.featured_slider .slick-dots').css('display', "none");
      });

      item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.featured_slider .slick-dots').css('display', "block");
      });
    }
  }

  /* 
  11. Init Popular Categories Slider
  */

  function initPopularSlider() {
    if ($('.popular_categories_slider').length) {
      var popularSlider = $('.popular_categories_slider');

      popularSlider.owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        autoplay: false,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1
          },
          575: {
            items: 2
          },
          640: {
            items: 3
          },
          768: {
            items: 4
          },
          991: {
            items: 5
          }
        }
      });

      if ($('.popular_categories_prev').length) {
        var prev = $('.popular_categories_prev');
        prev.on('click', function() {
          popularSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
        });
      }

      if ($('.popular_categories_next').length) {
        var next = $('.popular_categories_next');
        next.on('click', function() {
          popularSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
        });
      }
    }
  }

  /* 
  12. Init Banner 2 Slider
  */

  function initBanner2Slider() {
    if ($('.banner_2_slider').length) {
      var banner2Slider = $('.banner_2_slider');
      banner2Slider.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: true,
        nav: false,
        dots: true,
        dotsContainer: '.banner_2_dots',
        smartSpeed: 1200
      });
    }
  }

  /* 
  13. Init Arrivals Slider
  */

  function initArrivalsSlider() {
    if ($('.arrivals_slider').length) {
      var arrivalsSliders = $('.arrivals_slider');
      arrivalsSliders.each(function() {
        var arrivalsSlider = $(this);
        initASlider(arrivalsSlider);
      });
    }
  }

  function initASlider(as) {
    var arrivalsSlider = as;
    arrivalsSlider.on('init', function() {
        var activeItems = arrivalsSlider.find('.slick-slide.slick-active');
        for (var x = 0; x < activeItems.length - 1; x++) {
          var item = $(activeItems[x]);
          item.find('.border_active').removeClass('active');
          if (item.hasClass('slick-active')) {
            item.find('.border_active').addClass('active');
          }
        }
      }).on({
        afterChange: function(event, slick, current_slide_index, next_slide_index) {
          var activeItems = arrivalsSlider.find('.slick-slide.slick-active');
          activeItems.find('.border_active').removeClass('active');
          for (var x = 0; x < activeItems.length - 1; x++) {
            var item = $(activeItems[x]);
            item.find('.border_active').removeClass('active');
            if (item.hasClass('slick-active')) {
              item.find('.border_active').addClass('active');
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .slick({
        rows: 2,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        infinite: false,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              rows: 2,
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3,
              dots: true
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 575,
            settings: {
              rows: 2,
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2,
              dots: false
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              rows: 1,
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              dots: false
            }
          }
        ]
      });
  }

  /* 
  14. Init Arrivals Slider ZIndex
  */

  function arrivalsSliderZIndex() {
    // Hide slider dots on item hover
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('arrivals_slider_item');

    for (var x = 0; x < items.length; x++) {
      var item = items[x];
      item.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.arrivals_slider .slick-dots').css('display', "none");
      });

      item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.arrivals_slider .slick-dots').css('display', "block");
      });
    }
  }

  /* 
  15. Init Best Sellers Slider
  */

  function bestsellersSlider() {
    if ($('.bestsellers_slider').length) {
      var bestsellersSliders = $('.bestsellers_slider');
      bestsellersSliders.each(function() {
        var bestsellersSlider = $(this);

        initBSSlider(bestsellersSlider);
      })
    }
  }

  function initBSSlider(bss) {
    var bestsellersSlider = bss;

    bestsellersSlider.slick({
      rows: 2,
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      arrows: false,
      dots: true,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 6000,
      responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 1199,
          settings: {
            rows: 2,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            dots: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 991,
          settings: {
            rows: 2,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 575,
          settings: {
            rows: 1,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            dots: false
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  /* 
  16. Init Trends Slider
  */

  function initTrendsSlider() {
    if ($('.trends_slider').length) {
      var trendsSlider = $('.trends_slider');
      trendsSlider.owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        margin: 30,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        autoplay: false,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1
          },
          575: {
            items: 2
          },
          991: {
            items: 3
          }
        }
      });

      trendsSlider.on('click', '.trends_fav', function(ev) {
        $(ev.target).toggleClass('active');
      });

      if ($('.trends_prev').length) {
        var prev = $('.trends_prev');
        prev.on('click', function() {
          trendsSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
        });
      }

      if ($('.trends_next').length) {
        var next = $('.trends_next');
        next.on('click', function() {
          trendsSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
        });
      }
    }
  }

  /* 
  17. Init Reviews Slider
  */

  function initReviewsSlider() {
    if ($('.reviews_slider').length) {
      var reviewsSlider = $('.reviews_slider');

      reviewsSlider.owlCarousel({
        items: 3,
        loop: true,
        margin: 30,
        autoplay: false,
        nav: false,
        dots: true,
        dotsContainer: '.reviews_dots',
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1
          },
          768: {
            items: 2
          },
          991: {
            items: 3
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

  /* 
  18. Init Recently Viewed Slider
  */

  function initViewedSlider() {
    if ($('.viewed_slider').length) {
      var viewedSlider = $('.viewed_slider');

      viewedSlider.owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 30,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 6000,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1
          },
          575: {
            items: 2
          },
          768: {
            items: 3
          },
          991: {
            items: 4
          },
          1199: {
            items: 6
          }
        }
      });

      if ($('.viewed_prev').length) {
        var prev = $('.viewed_prev');
        prev.on('click', function() {
          viewedSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
        });
      }

      if ($('.viewed_next').length) {
        var next = $('.viewed_next');
        next.on('click', function() {
          viewedSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
        });
      }
    }
  }

  /* 
  19. Init Brands Slider
  */

  function initBrandsSlider() {
    if ($('.brands_slider').length) {
      var brandsSlider = $('.brands_slider');

      brandsSlider.owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        nav: false,
        dots: false,
        autoWidth: true,
        items: 8,
        margin: 42
      });

      if ($('.brands_prev').length) {
        var prev = $('.brands_prev');
        prev.on('click', function() {
          brandsSlider.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
        });
      }

      if ($('.brands_next').length) {
        var next = $('.brands_next');
        next.on('click', function() {
          brandsSlider.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
        });
      }
    }
  }

  /* 
  20. Init Timer
  */

  function initTimer() {
    if ($('.deals_timer_box').length) {
      var timers = $('.deals_timer_box');
      timers.each(function() {
        var timer = $(this);

        var targetTime;
        var target_date;

        // Add a date to data-target-time of the .deals_timer_box
        // Format: "Feb 17, 2018"
        if (timer.data('target-time') !== "") {
          targetTime = timer.data('target-time');
          target_date = new Date(targetTime).getTime();
        } else {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2);
          target_date = date.getTime();
        }

        // variables for time units
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

        var h = timer.find('.deals_timer_hr');
        var m = timer.find('.deals_timer_min');
        var s = timer.find('.deals_timer_sec');

        setInterval(function() {
          // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
          var current_date = new Date().getTime();
          var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
          console.log(seconds_left);

          // do some time calculations
          days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
          seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

          hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
          hours = hours + days * 24;
          seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;


          minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
          seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

          if (hours.toString().length < 2) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
          }
          if (minutes.toString().length < 2) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes;
          }
          if (seconds.toString().length < 2) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds;
          }

          // display results
          h.text(hours);
          m.text(minutes);
          s.text(seconds);

        }, 1000);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

My `custom.js` line number 45 is and all the functions have been defined with these names.

```
initCustomDropdown();
initPageMenu();
initDealsSlider();
initTabLines();
initFeaturedSlider();
featuredSliderZIndex();
initPopularSlider();
initBanner2Slider();
initFavs();
initArrivalsSlider();
arrivalsSliderZIndex();
bestsellersSlider();
initTabs();
initTrendsSlider();
initReviewsSlider();
initViewedSlider();
initBrandsSlider();
initTimer();
```

Any recommendations? Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the placeholder doesn't exist. you can surround the placeholder event handling with if.

Comment: Could you comment out the `.on` parts one after another from bottom to top and see which one is throwing the binding error? I think line 116 refers to `$('.custom_list a').on(...`, but I might be importing too few/much JS from your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix this part.

`var` `placeholder` was declared inside if block which makes it inaccessible outside if block.

```
var placeholder;
if ($('.custom_dropdown_placeholder').length && $('.custom_list').length) {
  placeholder = $('.custom_dropdown_placeholder');
  var list = $('.custom_list');
}
if (placeholder) {
  placeholder.on('click', function(ev) {
    if (list.hasClass('active')) {
      list.removeClass('active');
    } else {
      list.addClass('active');
    }

    $(document).one('click', function closeForm(e) {
      if ($(e.target).hasClass('clc')) {
        $(document).one('click', closeForm);
      } else {
        list.removeClass('active');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Does $('.custom_dropdown_placeholder') exist?

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: Are you still getting same error? if yes, then you need to add an if condition around placeholder.on to check if it is defined.

Comment: If $('.custom_dropdown_placeholder') doesn't exist you'll get the error. use "if" as I commented on your question.

Comment: dheeraj even after removing the code. the problem stil esxists

Comment: I need to see what changes you made before I can comment further.

Comment: i removed the file from root but problem not solving even removing cache

Comment: I don't get it. Error is related to placeholder variable. Did you make changes as per my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176580/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-raashid-din-dar).